# HTML5 Video Player functionality and issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm currently creating an HTML5 video player and there are some issues I'm having with it. My first issue is that the end time for my video isn't displaying correctly. I've created the javascript to display the current and duration time my video is play and it doesn't display that correctly.

Second, the volumeslider function doesn't work in Mozilla Firefox, however it works in Internet Explorer and Chrome.

Third, in my if/else statement, I stated if vid.muted and volumeslider == 0, set vid.volume = volumeslider.value / 100 else set vid.volume = volumeslider.value / 100 and nothing worked so I got rid of that code.

Just below is all of the code I have for my video player

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div#video_player_box {  width: 550px; 
                        background: #000;
                        margin: 0px auto; }

div#videos_controls_bar{ background: #333; 
                         padding: 10px; 
                         color: #CCC}

input#seekslider{width: 170px;}

input#volumeslider{width: 80px;}

</style>
<script> 
var vid, playbtn, seekslider, curtimetext, durtimetext, mutebtn, volumeslider; 

function initializePlayer () { 
    //set object references
    vid = document.getElementById("my_video");
    playbtn = document.getElementById("playpausebtn");
    seekslider = document.getElementById("seekslider");
    curtimetext = document.getElementById("curtimetext");
    durtimetext = document.getElementById("durtimetext");
    mutebtn = document.getElementById("mutebtn");
    volumeslider = document.getElementById("volumeslider");
    //Add event listeners
    playbtn.addEventListener("click", playPause, false);
    seekslider.addEventListener("change", vidSeek, false);  
    vid.addEventListener("timeupdate", seektimeupdate, false);
    mutebtn.addEventListener("click", vidmute, false);
    volumeslider.addEventListener("change", setvolume, false);


} 
window.onload = initializePlayer; 

function playPause() { 
    if (vid.paused) { 
        vid.play();
        playbtn.innerHTML = "Pause";  
    } else { 
        vid.pause(); 
        playbtn.innerHTML = "Play"; 
    }

}

function vidSeek () {
    var seekto = vid.duration * (seekslider.value / 100); 
    vid.currentTime = seekto; 

}

function seektimeupdate () { 
    var nt = vid.currentTime * (100 / vid.duration); 
    seekslider.value = nt;
    var curmins = Math.floor(vid.currentTime / 60); 
    var cursecs = Math.floor(vid.currentTime - curmins * 60); 
    var durmins = Math.floor(vid.duration / 60); 
    var dursecs = Math.floor(vid.duration - durmins * 60); 
    if(cursecs < 10) { cursecs = "0"+cursecs; }
    if(dursecs < 10) { dursecs = "0"+dursecs; }
    if(curmins < 10) { curmins = "0"+curmins; }
    if(durmins < 10) { durmins = "0"+dursecs; }
    curtimetext.innerHTML = curmins+":"+cursecs; 
    durtimetext.innerHTML = durmins+":"+dursecs;
}
function vidmute () { 
    if (vid.muted) { 
        vid.muted = false;
        mutebtn.innerHTML = "Mute"; 

    } else { 
        vid.muted = true; 
        mutebtn.innerHTML = "Unmute"; 
    }


}

function setvolume () {
    vid.volume = volumeslider.value / 100;

}
</script>

<title>HTML5 Video Player</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div id = "video_player_box">
   <video id="my_video"  width="550" height="320" autoplay> 
     <source src="videos/Tom_and_Jerry.mp4">
   </video>
  <div id="videos_controls_bar">
    <button id="playpausebtn">Pause</button>
    <input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1">
    <span id ="curtimetext"></span> / <span id ="durtimetext"></span>
    <button id="mutebtn">Mute</button>
    <input id="volumeslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm having trouble attaching the zip file onto here so if anyone needs my email address, it's ghaynes109@gmail.com

Comment: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I would recommend using something like http://jPlayer.org. It will use HTML5, and has a flash fallback for browsers that don't support HTML5 video, which is super quirky right now. Another advantage is that jPlayer will allow you to create an interface using HTML, that will be consistent across platforms. I'm a Firefox user, and volume control using jPlayer/HTML5 works great. The documentation is extensive, and it will help you understand what to expect, like what metadata (duration, title) will be available when. You may need to preload the video or something to get what you're looking for.